# Blueimp Gallery integration issue

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, gallery, blueimp

I am attempting to use the [blueimp gallery](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery) and I believe I have entered the all of the code snips as needed but still when I click on an image they do not load with the contols.

```
cat index.html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="js/blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                        <div class="page-header">
                                <h1>
                                        test <small>test</small>
                                </h1>
                        </div>
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery">
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="blueimp-gallery-display"></a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>
<script src="js/init.js"></script>
<div id="links">
<A HREF="images/photo1.jpg"> <IMG HEIGHT=50 WIDTH=50 SRC="images/photo1.jpg"></A>
<A HREF="images/photo2.jpg"> <IMG HEIGHT=50 WIDTH=50 SRC="images/photo2.jpg"></A>
<A HREF="images/photo3.jpg"> <IMG HEIGHT=50 WIDTH=50 SRC="images/photo3.jpg"></A>
<A HREF="images/photo4.jpg"> <IMG HEIGHT=50 WIDTH=50 SRC="images/photo4.jpg"></A>
</div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cat js/init.js
var links = document.getElementById('links').getElementsByTagName('a'),
    options = {
        // Start an automatic slideshow with a delay of 5 seconds between slides:
                 interval: 5000,
        // Set to true to initialize the Gallery with carousel specific options:
                  carousel: false
                displayClass: 'blueimp-gallery-display',
                controlsClass: 'blueimp-gallery-controls',
                singleClass: 'blueimp-gallery-single',                  
                leftEdgeClass: 'blueimp-gallery-left',
                rightEdgeClass: 'blueimp-gallery-right',
                enableKeyboardNavigation: true,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                   },
                  gallery = blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
```

I have used some light bootstrap before and this does not seems in function the same or im just overlooking something.

Answer (score 8):

You need to set class **blueimp-gallery-controls**

```
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls">
```

Comment: @chris Apologies for resurrecting this, but can you mark this answer as accepted if it worked for you?